# AspectJ: ClassLoading issue when trying to use external aop.xml file

Tags: java, classloader, aop, aspectj

I m trying to externalize the configuration of aop.xml so I removed the `aop.xml` from `META-INF` and made it available in the server for manual configuration by sys admins.

When I try to use an external aop.xml using

```
-Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration="file:D:\Workspace\tomcat7\shared\lib\aop.xml"
```

I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot register non aspect: aspectclass....` mainly because the aj casses are not loaded by `AppClassLoader` yet at that time. And the next time it tries to register the aspects from the `WebAppClassLoader` ( after all the classes are loaded), it works fine, but i still get the exceptions logged from the 1st attempt to register it.

The exception is caught and logged at `ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java` line 307.

when the following line is called:
                success = registerAspects(weaver, loader, definitions);

the exception is caught and logged.

```
    try {
        registerOptions(weaver, loader, definitions);
        registerAspectExclude(weaver, loader, definitions);
        registerAspectInclude(weaver, loader, definitions);
        success = registerAspects(weaver, loader, definitions);
        registerIncludeExclude(weaver, loader, definitions);
        registerDump(weaver, loader, definitions);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        trace.error("register definition failed", ex);
        success = false;
        warn("register definition failed", (ex instanceof AbortException) ? null : ex);
    }
```

the exception is thrown excactly in the following line in BcelWeaver.java

```
if (type.isAspect()) {
      ......
} else {
        // FIXME AV - better warning upon no such aspect from aop.xml
        RuntimeException ex = new RuntimeException("Cannot register non aspect: " + type.getName() + " , " + aspectName);
        if (trace.isTraceEnabled()) {
            trace.exit("addLibraryAspect", ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
```

How can I prevent the classLoader from logging the error to the console, when the aspects are not loaded yet. I was thinking of commenting the line that logs the exception from the source file and rebuilding the aspectjweaver jar file, but was looking for a better solution without modifying the aspectj source.

Comment: Please mention what versions are you using and provide a link to `ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java` or consider including the code in your question

Comment: added code snippet that is throwing the exception.

Comment: (not too familiar with AspectJ) What I don't understand is what difference does it make where the configuration file is, (under `META-INF` or an external location). How can this change the classes that are found or not? Or do you get this message when you are not using the system property also?

Comment: the difference is that I was to put the aop.xml externally to allow system admins to modify pointcut expressions per environment and without having to rebuild and redeploy the app. I m also not sure why using the system property behave different than META-INF eventhough the code seems to behave the same.

Comment: I assume you are using the agent method for Load Time Weaving? Which server do you use?

Comment: yes, I m using the javaagent option, the exceptions are being thrown in the custom ClassLoader that is inside the agent. I m using tomcat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure that there is an easy way out of your problem. As I said I haven't worked with AspectJ before but I believe this is a mis-behaviour of the weaver.

**Problem description:** During boot the agent tries to apply weaving other not only to the `WebAppClassLoader` but to the whole classloader chain (once per classloader) i.e. to: `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`, `sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader`, `org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader` (the tomcat's classloader). When you use the `META-INF/aop.xml` approach it disables weaving for the above classloaders because "a configuration file is not available" (if you enable `verbose` mode you can see those messages in console). When you use the file configuration approach, a configuration *is available for all the classloaders in the chain*. Since it does find a configuration file, the agent parses the definitions, it does not find the aspects' class and shows the error.

The weird thing is that, as described in the [configuration documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html) if you use the `WeavingURLClassLoader` approach for load time weaving, *"... it also allows the user to explicitly restrict by class loader which classes can be woven"*. So this is actually a feature (!) that the classloader approach can have but the agent approach doesn't. (Unfortunately I was not able to use this approach)

**The good (and the bad) news:** The good news is that you can easily create your own agent that will ignore the weaving for the aforementioned classloaders. The bad news is that restricting weaving per classloader is not enough because if you have other applications in the same server, Tomcat would still use the `WebAppClassLoader` to load them so you would still get error messages for those applications. (Perhaps you could extend the classes below to filter packages/classes as well, in that case).

Below you can find two class for the modified agent. To use them you would need to do the following:

- Un-jar the `aspectjweaver.jar` to a folder
- Under `org/aspectj/weaver/loadtime` create a new folder `filter` to match the package name and put there the two new classes after you compile them.
- Edit the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file and change the line

  `Premain-Class: org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Agent` to
     `Premain-Class: org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.filter.FilterAgent`
- Re-jar and you have your new agent ready.
- When starting the JVM you can now pass a new system property with a comma separated list of the classloaders you would like to ignore i.e. `-Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.filter=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader,sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader,org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader` ( I have set `CATALINA_OPTS` to do that).

The classes are a modified copy of the original agent's classes `Agent` and `ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter`. The only code I have added is the part that parses the above system property if it exists and to ignore calls for the classloaders we are not interested in.

Use at your own risk :) I hope that helps

```
package org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.filter;

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class FilterAgent {

    private static Instrumentation s_instrumentation;

    // Use our own version of ClassFileTransformer that would filter out selected classloaders 
    private static ClassFileTransformer s_transformer = new ClassPreprocessorFilteredAdapter();

    /**
     * JSR-163 preMain Agent entry method
     *
     * @param options
     * @param instrumentation
     */
    public static void premain(String options, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        /* Handle duplicate agents */
        if (s_instrumentation != null) {
            return;
        }
        s_instrumentation = instrumentation;
        s_instrumentation.addTransformer(s_transformer);
    }

    public static Instrumentation getInstrumentation() {
        if (s_instrumentation == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Java 5 was not started with preMain -javaagent for AspectJ");
        }
        return s_instrumentation;
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.filter;

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj;
import org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessor;


public class ClassPreprocessorFilteredAdapter implements ClassFileTransformer {

    /**
     * Concrete preprocessor.
     */
    private static ClassPreProcessor s_preProcessor;

    private static Map<String, String> ignoredClassloaderNames = new HashMap<String, String>();

    static {
        try {
            s_preProcessor = new Aj();
            s_preProcessor.initialize();


            String ignoredLoaders = System.getProperty("org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.filter", "");
            if (ignoredLoaders.length() > 0) {
                String[] loaders = ignoredLoaders.split(",");

                for (String s : loaders) {
                    s = s.trim();
                    ignoredClassloaderNames.put(s, s);
                    System.out.println("---> Will filtered out classloader: " + s);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("could not initialize JSR163 preprocessor due to: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Invokes the weaver to modify some set of input bytes.
     * 
     * @param loader the defining class loader
     * @param className the name of class being loaded
     * @param classBeingRedefined is set when hotswap is being attempted
     * @param protectionDomain the protection domain for the class being loaded
     * @param bytes the incoming bytes (before weaving)
     * @return the woven bytes
     */
    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] bytes) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        if (classBeingRedefined != null) {
            System.err.println("INFO: (Enh120375):  AspectJ attempting reweave of '" + className + "'");
        }

        String loaderName = loader.getClass().getName();
        if (shouldIgnoreClassLoader(loaderName)) {
            return bytes;
        }
        return s_preProcessor.preProcess(className, bytes, loader, protectionDomain);
    }

    private boolean shouldIgnoreClassLoader(String loaderName) {
        boolean result = false;
        String ignoredLoader = ignoredClassloaderNames.get(loaderName);
        if (ignoredLoader != null) {
            result = true;    // if the loader name exists in the map we will ignore weaving
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks for the detailed recomandation. since those exception are just caught and logged and not impacting the flow of the application, what if I just comment out the line of code that logs the error and rebuild the aspectj weaver? I was looking for a solution that would be portable across multiple app servers and not tie it with tomcat or a specific app sever.

Comment: @Sammy this is not tied to a specific server. You would just pass a different property i.e. change the classloaders to ignore instead of using `StandardClassLoader` you would add whatever classloader the other server uses (or you could add both). You can of course comment out the message but that would also hide meaningful errors to you e.g. if some of your aspect classes is indeed missing when weaving `WebAppClassLoader`. I believe this is a feature that will be added to AspectJ at some point so such a hack will not be necessary. The error as it is now, does not make sense

Comment: @Sammy also during the investigation of this issue it came up that Spring uses something similar. You might be able to use that if you use Spring

Comment: I can also use the property if (loader.equals(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()) and hide the error only if it is a systemClassLoader. I will keep the question open for little more time, in case someone suggest a better solution. otherwise, your answer will be the accepted one ;)

Comment: @Sammy I think this would work only for the first classloader i.e. the `AppClassLoader` but yes you can experiment with it. You could filter packages/classes too. A more elegant approach would be to disable weaving as in the case where it does not find a configuration file but I would have to change another class and I didn't want to get deeper in its initialization logic.

Answer (score 4):

If you need the feature to exclude classloaders from weaving with the agent approach, there is a [developer build](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php) available providing a new command line switch `-Daj.weaving.loadersToSkip` to do that. The topic is being discussed on a [thread of the AspectJ users mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/threads.html#14164). The feature will probably make it into AspectJ 1.7.4, but is not available in 1.7.3 yet.

**Update:**

The [feature](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=368046) did make it into AspectJ 1.7.4 even though it is not explicitly mentioned in the [release notes](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-174.html), but listed under [resolved issues](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&list_id=10841624&product=AspectJ&query_format=advanced&target_milestone=1.7.4) for that release.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is changing the LOG Level for the error message from ERROR to DEBUG, as I don't see this as an ERROR ( at least in my case ). this case I can still see the error when I enable the DEBUG level. so I modified the source file below and rebuild my aspectjweaver-1.7.1.jar

```
try {
    registerOptions(weaver, loader, definitions);
    registerAspectExclude(weaver, loader, definitions);
    registerAspectInclude(weaver, loader, definitions);
    success = registerAspects(weaver, loader, definitions);
    registerIncludeExclude(weaver, loader, definitions);
    registerDump(weaver, loader, definitions);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //(CHANGE 1) trace.error("register definition failed", ex);
    trace.debug( "register definition failed" + ex.getMessage());
    success = false;
    // (CHANGE 2) warn("register definition failed", (ex instanceof AbortException) ? null : ex);
    debug("register definition failed" + ((ex instanceof AbortException) ? null : ex));
}
```