# Reusable aspects jar

Tags: aop, aspectj, reusability

We are going to start using aspectsJ in our production Java standalone apps soon. So, I am trying to come up with a jar that has aspects so I can weave them to the production apps without any code change.
I am trying to create a separate project (MyAspects.jar)for aspects and include them to the existing java class path to minimize code changes. While I am adding the aop.xml to the production application jar's META-INF folder.

While running the app, I am using -javaagent:pathto\aspectjweaver.jar and include MyAspects.jar in the folder that is on the classpath.

But when execute it, it errors out with below details. Including whole stacktrace.
I am using aspectjweaver-1.8.4.jar.

```
[AppClassLoader@553f5d07] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.4 built on Thursday Nov 6, 2014 at 20:19:21 GMT
[AppClassLoader@553f5d07] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@553f5d07
[AppClassLoader@553f5d07] info using configuration file:/C:/riskEventLoader/lib/risk-event-loader.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@553f5d07] info register aspect com.aspect.generic.GenericAspect
Jan 12, 2015 8:37:15 AM org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace error
SEVERE: register definition failed java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot register non aspect: com$aspect$generic$GenericAspect , com.aspect.generic.GenericAspect
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryAspect(BcelWeaver.java:219)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.registerAspects(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:485)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.registerDefinitions(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:304)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:171)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(Aj.java:340)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.getWeavingAdaptor(Aj.java:345)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$WeaverContainer.getWeaver(Aj.java:319)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:113)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:54)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:169)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:365)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

---

**Edit (by kriegaex):**

I am adding some code snippets here which were previously posted as comments so as to make them more readable and qualify the question for reopening.

**Aspect:**

Please note that I have fixed some syntax errors, namely missing leading `*` signifying method return type in the two `execution()` pointcuts. I also simplified the logging statements.

```java
package com.aspect.generic;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class GenericAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void myTraceCall() {}

    @Around("execution(* com.test.riskcheck..*(..))")
    public Object myTrace(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("[BEFORE] " + thisJoinPoint);
        Object retVal = null;
        try {
            retVal = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("[AFTER]  " + thisJoinPoint + " -> retval = " + retVal);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

**AspectJ LTW configuration file *aop.xml*:**

I also simplified this file a bit. It still exposes the same problem as the one posted by the question's author for the same reason.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.aspect.generic.GenericAspect"/>
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="com.test.riskcheck..*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Comment: Sure, you can do that, no problem. But what is the conrete question? This is StackOverflow. Do you have a technical problem related to programming? If so, please specify it.

Comment: I am seeing below error when I run the java application on cmd.
SEVERE: register definition failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot register non aspect: com$aspect$generic$Gener
icAspect , com.aspect.generic.GenericAspect

Comment: I have a pre-compiled java project as a jar. I included aop.xml into the META-INF folder in the jar as below 

<aspectj>
 <aspects>
  <aspect name="com.aspect.generic.GenericAspect"/>
 </aspects>
  <weaver options="-verbose -debug -showWeaveInfo">
  <include within="com.test.riskcheck.dao.*" />
  <include within="com.test.riskcheck.service.*"/>
  <include within="com.test.riskcheck.data.*"/>
  <include within="com.test.riskcheck.utils.*"/>
  <include within="com.aspect.generic.*"/>
 </weaver>
</aspectj>

Created another project with aspects and included that as jar in call cmd.But it errs out.

Comment: Thanks for the question update. Would you mind also showing some code? I would like to see the aspect(s), for instance. And can you tell us which kind of container your code runs in?

Comment: Its a Java code (jar) running locally on my PC cmd.

Comment: @Aspect > public class GenericAspect {
@Pointcut("execution(* (..))")
public void myTraceCall(){} 

@Around("execution( com.test.riskcheck..*(..))")
public Object myTrace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
{System.out.println("myTrace:before call "+joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName()+"."+joinPoint.getSignature().getNam‌​e());
Object retVal = null;

try{retVal = joinPoint.proceed();}
finally{System.out.println("myTrace:after call "+joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName()+"."+joinPoint.getSignature().getNam‌​e() + " retval=" +retVal);}
return retVal;
}
}

Comment: You really should update the question and not post unreadable code snippets in a comment. I had to reformat everything manually in an editor in order to be able to read it at all.

Comment: Because the question is on hold and there are not enough reopen votes (which is a pity because now it contains more info than before), I am going to answer here: Your file *C:\riskEventLoader\lib\risk-event-loader.jar* contains an *aop.xml* file which specifies `com.aspect.generic.GenericAspect` as an aspect, but the corresponding class file cannot be found in this JAR file. The *aop.xml* and the class file should be in the same file, i.e. in the aspect JAR.

Comment: Your current issue looks like a [possible duplicate of AspectJ: ClassLoading issue when trying to use external aop.xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18194719/359284).