# Is it possible to run wicket-metrics with aspectJ on wicket 6?

Tags: java, maven, wicket, aspectj

I know that `wicket-metrics` is an experimental version since `Wicket 7.3.0`, but I am working on a project based on Wicket 6.17.0.
Has anyone tried to run the `wicket-metrics` module with with `Wicket 6`?

What I tried:

- cloned the wicket git repo - https://github.com/apache/wicket and added the `wicket-metrics` module to my project, instructing the pom.xml to use the dependencies from my project.
- added the `aop.xml` to my META-INF folder and start JmxReporter in my `init()` method.

But I get errors that required `WicketFilterInitAspect` cannot be registered (it is included in my aop.xml file).

aop.xml file in META-INF folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <!--<weaver options="-nowarn">-->
        <!--<include within="org.apache.wicket..*"/>-->
    <!--</weaver>-->
    <aspects>
        <!-- required -->
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.WicketFilterInitAspect" />
        <!-- optional -->
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.model.LoadableDetachableModelLoadAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.requesthandler.IRequestHandlerDetachAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.requesthandler.IRequestHandlerRespondAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.resource.IResourceCreateAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.behavior.BehaviorCreateAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.component.ComponentCreateAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.component.ComponentOnConfigureAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.component.ComponentOnDetachAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.component.ComponentOnInitializeAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.component.ComponentOnRenderAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.component.ComponentSetResponsePageAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.ajax.IPartialPageRequestHandlerAddAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.ajax.IPartialPageRequestHandlerAppendJavaScriptAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.ajax.IPartialPageRequestHandlerPrependJavaScriptAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.resource.ResourceReferenceCreateAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.markup.WicketTagCreateAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.request.WicketFilterRequestCycleUrlAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.request.WicketFilterRequestCycleAspect" />
        <aspect name="org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.session.SessionCountListenerAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

So my feeling is that this should be generally possible and I am wondering if anyone has ever succeeded or has an idea?

Part of my strack trace:

```
[NoCallStackClassLoader@290dbf45] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.2 built on Thursday Aug 14, 2014 at 21:45:02 GMT
[NoCallStackClassLoader@290dbf45] info register classloader javax.management.remote.rmi.NoCallStackClassLoader@290dbf45
[NoCallStackClassLoader@290dbf45] info register aspect org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.WicketFilterInitAspect
May 26, 2016 8:23:02 PM org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace error
SEVERE: register definition failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot register non aspect: org$apache$wicket$metrics$aspects$WicketFilterInitAspect , org.apache.wicket.metrics.aspects.WicketFilterInitAspect
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryAspect(BcelWeaver.java:219)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.registerAspects(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:485)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.registerDefinitions(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:304)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:171)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(Aj.java:339)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.getWeavingAdaptor(Aj.java:344)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$WeaverContainer.getWeaver(Aj.java:318)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:113)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:54)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.NoCallStackClassLoader.findClass(NoCallStackClassLoader.java:126)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$1.run(RMIConnector.java:2157)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$1.run(RMIConnector.java:2144)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.<clinit>(RMIConnector.java:2178)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.objectToBind(RMIConnectorServer.java:752)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:408)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:768)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:456)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:257)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
```

I also get some of these errors related to spring framework:

```
[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] error can't determine superclass of missing type javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult
when weaving type org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.AnnotationJCacheOperationSource
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] error can't determine superclass of missing type javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult
when weaving type org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.AnnotationJCacheOperationSource
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] error can't determine whether missing type javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult is an instance of org.apache.wicket.Component
when weaving type org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.AnnotationJCacheOperationSource
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] error can't determine superclass of missing type javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult
when weaving type org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.AnnotationJCacheOperationSource
when weaving classes 
when weaving
```

Comment: Please show us the errors.

Comment: @martin-g, I added part of the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [AspectJ: ClassLoading issue when trying to use external aop.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194719/aspectj-classloading-issue-when-trying-to-use-external-aop-xml-file)

It looks related.

Sorry, I cannot help much than this.

Comment: Thanks! Initializing the WicketMetrics filter name before the spring context was initialized solved those in consistencies. I also declared all wicket-aspects as spring beans in order to work together with my external aop.xml file. But unfortunately I can now only measure method execution pointcuts due to the limitations of spring AOP. Do you have any idea/thoughts regarding this?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late response. I think in this case we have to find a way to tell Spring to handle annotations of AspectJ. Have you tried <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> @lapadets